# How to disable secure credentials password?

Tags: wi-fi, security

On DesireZ running android 2.2 I've run into a rather annoying problem. The phone forces me to make a credentials password for WIFI, and then I have to enter it before the phone will connect to a secured wifi network.

I don't care about the security of my wifi passwords being compromised in the event of my phone being stolen, so I would like to disable this annoyance.

I cannot find any setting or way of doing this, however. Is it possible? Or is there an app which can remember and automatically enter the password on boot-up?

Thanks.

[edit]I can uncheck the "use secure credentials" option, but that simply prevents me from connecting to any wifi connection which requires a password. Attempting to enter a password for the wifi connection first prompts me for a new secure credentials password...[/edit]

The minimum password length is 8, so it won't let me leave it blank.

Comment: or leave the password blank

Comment: @LieRyan It won't let me leave it blank, minimum is 8 characters. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Keystore Unlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.chunky.AutoKeystore) if your phone is rooted and [Keystore Notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.chunky.KeystoreActivator) if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried disabling the "Use secure credentials" option in `Menu -> Settings -> Location & security`, under "Credentials storage" section?

Answer (score 1):

Did you uncheck "Settings > Location & Security > Use secure credentials"?

EDIT: or leave the password blank

Answer (score 0):

Besides disabling the "Use secure credentials", if it still asks for the password upon joining a Wi-Fi network, make it happy by going back to `Settings => Security => Set password` (Under "Credential storage"; applicable to HTC Desire device). It won't bug you anymore after that